# React for user role doesn't work - discord.py

Tags: python, reactjs, discord, bots, roles

I'm just building a discord bot for my discord server with discord.py.
I made a code, but it won't work. It creates the message and you can react. Even the first debug message comes: User reacted to message.

But it won't give me the role.
This is my code:

```
async def reactMsg(ctx):

    send_sub = await ctx.message.channel.send("React to this message to subscribe NPT.")
    reactions = ['✅']
    for i in reactions:
        await send_sub.add_reaction(i)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    #You forgot to await the bot.get_channel
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    #Put the following Line
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)

    print("Debug: User reacted to message")

    # only work if it is the client
    if payload.user_id == client.user.id:
        return

    if payload.message_id == 943634886642765874 and reaction.emoji == '✅':
        roles = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='TrackerSub')
        await member.add_roles(roles)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member)
        print("Debug: Give role to user")
```

Any ideas what I made wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Code

I see a couple things wrong, let's walk through some changes you can make to make this a bit better:

```py
async def react_msg(ctx):
    # Send a message, no need for `ctx.message.channel.send`, it's redundant.
    message = await ctx.send("React to this message to subscribe NPT.")
    reactions = ['✅']
    for i in reactions:
        await message.add_reaction(i)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    # We don't want to do operations if the bot is the one who reacted
    if payload.user_id == client.user.id: 
        return
    
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    if channel is None: # This channel wasn't found
        return None
    
    guild = channel.guild
    if guild is None: # This reaction was not in a guild
        return
    
    member = payload.member
    if member is None:
        try:
            member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id) or (await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id))
        except discord.NotFound: # This member wasn't found
            return None
    
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
    if reaction is None: # This reaction was not found
        return
    
    # The message ID is not right or the emoji was wrong
    if payload.message_id != 943634886642765874 or str(reaction.emoji) != '✅':
        return
    
    roles = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='TrackerSub')
    if roles is None: 
        # This role was not found, return.
        return
    
    await member.add_roles(roles)
    await reaction.remove(member)
```

### Remember

Having a good `on_command_error` is important to Discord bot development. Using the traceback is always going to be a good friend when debugging things like this.

Comment: can you maybe tell me from where you got the payload.message_id ? I'm just a bit confused.